# Python GTK+ 3 Safe Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk3

So what should I run at the beginning of my program to make it thread-safe (or thread-aware as I've read in some places):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib, GObject
import threading

GLib.threads_init()     # ?
GObject.threads_init()  # YES!
Gdk.threads_init()      # ?

my_app()

def my_threaded_func():
   Glib.idle_add(lambda: some_gui_action())
   Glib.timeout_add(300, lambda: some_gui_action())

t = threading.Thread(target=my_thread_func)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

Gtk.main()
```

Then, what should I do in my threads? Some kind of lock? Is it safe to use Python's threading library or should I use something in GLib, GObject or Gdk? I know there is a ton of questions/answers/examples out there, but they all contradict each other, are not for Gtk+ 3, or not for Python, or simply incomplete, and even what I considered the official docs for Python GI (http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) does not even mention the existence of GObject.threads_init() and Gdk.threads_init().

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading

.. but, [Gdk.threads_init() is deprecated](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk-threads-init), and I'd recommmend to:

- Not call Gdk.threads_init, Gdk.threads_enter/leave at all
- Use GLib.idle_add instead of Gdk.threads_add_idle (or any other Gdk.threads_* function)
- Push things touching Gdk/Gtk to the main thread using GLib.idle/timeout_add

Why?:

- Not calling Gdk.threads_init means there will be no lock, which is OK if you never access GDK from another thread.
- Gdk.threads_enter does nothing since there is no lock.
- GLib.idle_add is equal to [Gdk.threads_add_idle](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk-threads-add-idle-full) in this case.

Regarding other libs:

- Some GI modules can emit certain signals/callbacks in other threads (in GStreamer the GstPlayBin::about-to-finish signal for example); even if you don't use Python threads in your code at all. Gdk/Gtk code can't be called in them directly, use idle_add there as well if needed.
- Many parts of GLib/GStreamer are thread safe and can be called from other threads.

tl;dr: **Only GObject.threads_init()**, **in threads** push all Gtk/Gdk code to the main thread using **GLib.idle_add**

Comment: The link you posted uses `Gdk.threads_init()`. Could you link to the source mentioning it's deprecated? And, could you explain why `GLib.idle_add()` instead of `Gdk.threads_add_idle()`? Thanks.

Comment: @lazca My app hasn't crashed since I implemented your suggestions. Thanks a lot for that. Two more things, what is the rationale behind using `GObject.threads_init()` and not `GLib.threads_init()`? After all we are using `GLib.add_idle()` to synchronize with the main thread. And I've read people saying that it's better to use parallel processes instead of threads. Could you comment? Thanks again.

Comment: `(GLib.threads_init is GObject.threads_init) == True`. It's just an alias.. as pointed out in the PyGObject wiki page it's not related to GObject or GLib, but still there for historical reasons. You can think of it as `gi.threads_init()`. As also pointed out on the wiki page, it's not needed any more since 3.10.2.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a must to read document if anyone is going to use GTK in multithreaded code.
https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GdkLock

This document really helped me to understand how to run GTK from C as well as from python (through PyGTK just to import gtk in python) in a single process. Though the GDK Lock can be avoided in Linux by `XInitThreads()` it is not a solution for Windows. The Functions like `g_idle_add()` or `g_timeout_add()` are the generic solution to prevent GUI crush. However gdk_threads_enter() and gdk_thread_leave() are not completely useless yet. That document clarifies how to safely use those locks if someone wants to update GUI from different threads or from custom event handler or from `g_idle_add()` callbacks.