# Video player in gtk using opencv gets stuck

Tags: python, opencv, gtk

I am trying to simply play a video in gtk environment using opencv code in python. In order to achieve it I made a glade file that contains a toplevel window, a file menu, a drawing area and a file chooser dialog. When user select a file, code starts a thread that calls function VideoPlayerDA that starts reading video and after every frame it generates a queue_draw signal to display frame in drawing area. The problem however is that after few frames the whole UI freezes and becomes unresponsive, video gets stuck. 
Tools: I am using *Gtk version 3.22.11, python 3.5.3, OpenCV version 3.3.0 on debian stretch*.
PS: cv2.waitkey also seems to be not working.

```
import cv2
import time
import threading
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

GObject.threads_init()

mymutex = threading.Lock()
dimg = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file('test.jpg')

def VideoPlayerDA(filename,drawing_area):
    global dimg,dimg_available
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        mymutex.acquire()
        ret, img = cap.read()
        if img is not None:
            boxAllocation = drawing_area.get_allocation()
            img = cv2.resize(img, (boxAllocation.width,\
                                   boxAllocation.height))

            img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # opencv by default load BGR colorspace. Gtk supports RGB hance the conversion
            dimg = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(img.tostring(),
                                                  GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,False,8,
                                                  img.shape[1],
                                                  img.shape[0],
                                                  img.shape[2]*img.shape[1],None,None)

            #time.sleep(0.03)     
            drawing_area.queue_draw()
            mymutex.release()       
            time.sleep(0.03)
            #if ((cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF) == ord('q')):
            #    break
        else:
            mymutex.release()
            break

    print('end of file')

class video_player_gui:

    def on_main_window_destroy(self,object):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_open_activate(self,widget):
        response = self.file_chooser.run()
        if response == 0:
            self.filename = self.file_chooser.get_filename()            
            thread = threading.Thread(target = VideoPlayerDA, args=(self.filename, self.drawing_area,))
            thread.daemon = True
            thread.start()
            self.file_chooser.hide()
        else:
            pass

    def on_drawing_area_draw(self,widget,cr):
        global dimg
        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, dimg.copy(), 0, 0)
        cr.paint()

    def __init__(self):
        self.gladefile = '/home/nouman/Development/Glade/P2/OpenCv_integration_test.glade'
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.main_window = self.builder.get_object("main_window")
        self.file_chooser = self.builder.get_object("file_chooser")
        self.drawing_area = self.builder.get_object("drawing_area")
        self.main_window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main =  video_player_gui()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're calling `drawing_area.queue_draw()` from a thread. Gtk isn't thread safe; try doing that from the main thread instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150914/python-gtk-3-safe-threading) for info about threading in Gtk.

Comment: I did that because only my thread knows that a new frame is ready to be displayed, so it has to generate a draw signal.I am very new to python or threading. I worked mostly with FPGAs or microcontrollers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for now for anyone who will be getting same problem. I was using a global variable dimg without thread synchronization. Synchronizing threads before use of variable solved the problem. Edit on_drawing_area_draw as following will solve the issue

```
def on_drawing_area_draw(self,widget,cr):
    global dimg
    mymutex.acquire()
    Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, dimg.copy(), 0, 0)
    cr.paint()
    mymutex.release()
```